# Why did I get an 1 on a reserved bit of IA32_MTRRCAP register?

Tags: memory-management, x86-64, intel, mmu

I'm trying to do some memory management on xen-4.5.0, and get confused with something about MTRR(Memory-type-range-register). While I was trying to get the value of IA32_MTRRCAP register, I got value 1d0a.

However, in the Intel manual released in December 2016, bits 12-63 of IA32_MTRRCAP register are all marked reserved, while I got an 1 on bit 12. Why?

Meanwhile, when I was trying to read memory information from MTRRs, I could not find most of memory addresses in them.

I've tried these on several machines with Intel Skylake processors, and their situations are the same. But on machines with Intel Haswell processors, the value of IA32_MTRRCAP has nothing strange, I can also read all memory information from MTRRs.

Did the programming way of MTRRs change in Skylake? I can only guess in this way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the values read are correct - as it seems they are.
A reserved bit doesn't have to be zero, *reserved* more closely means "used internally by the Intel engineerings".

> **1.3.2 Reserved Bits and Software Compatibility**
>
> In many register and memory layout descriptions, certain bits are marked as reserved. When bits are marked as
>   reserved, it is essential for compatibility with future processors that software treat these bits as having a future,
>   though unknown, effect.
>
> *The behavior of reserved bits should be regarded as not only undefined, but unpredictable*.
>
> Software should follow these guidelines in dealing with reserved bits:
>
> - *Do not depend on the states of any reserved bits when testing the values of registers that contain such bits*.
>     Mask out the reserved bits before testing.
> - Do not depend on the states of any reserved bits when storing to memory or to a register.
> - Do not depend on the ability to retain information written into any reserved bits.
> - When loading a register, always load the reserved bits with the values indicated in the documentation, if any,
>     or reload them with values previously read from the same register.
>
> **NOTE**
>   Avoid any software dependence upon the state of reserved bits in Intel 64 and IA-32 registers.
>   Depending upon the values of reserved register bits will make software dependent upon the unspecified manner in which the processor handles these bits. Programs that depend upon reserved values risk incompatibility with future processors.

---

MTTRs have not changed in Skylake, their architectural behaviour is still the one defined in the manual you mentioned.